# Apple's vim always used instead of homebrew

Tags: macos, vim, path, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm seeing something very odd, and honestly I'm stumped.

The version of vim that comes with mac is outdated (7.3 instead of 7.4). I'm trying to install vim from homebrew, and I want to use that one instead of the default apple version.

I ran "`brew install vim`". It installed correctly in `/usr/local/bin/vim`. All good.

When I run "`which vim`", it prints "`/usr/local/bin/vim`". The Apple version of vim is installed at `/usr/bin/vim`. So the which command is telling me that I'm using the homebrew version of vim.

However, when I actually run vim, it still runs the Apple version

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul  9 2015 23:58:42)
Compiled by root@apple.com
...
```

If I run the homebrew version explicitly, I see this:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 23 2015 18:16:35)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-898
Compiled by Homebrew
...
```

I even tried moving `/usr/bin/vim` to `/usr/bin/vim73` to try to force using the homebrew version. However, when I did this, here is what I see when I try to run vim:

```
$ vim --version
-bash: /usr/bin/vim: No such file or directory
$
```

What is going on? How can I get it to run the homebrew version of vim?

Comment: Do you have an alias? Use `type` instead of `which` to check. In bash `which` is not a shell builtin, but `type` is.

Comment: The other obvious problem is the hash table if you haven't restarted your shell: `hash -l` shows the contents of the hash table in bash.

Comment: Ah thanks! When I type "type vim", I see "vim is hashed (/usr/bin/vim)". When I type "hash -l", I do see vim in the list.

Comment: To fix it the hacky way, I added 'alias vim="/usr/bin/local/vim"' to my .bash_profile. That seems to work. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Don't add an alias, no need to modify .bash_profile. Let the path do it for you. A fresh shell will get a fresh hash table, or just do `hash -r` to clear the hash table and let it get built again.

Comment: I've tried quitting the terminal, and I've definitely resett the computer, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: please also add the output of `alias vim`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Start a new shell session and it’ll work.

Bash caches executables’ paths so when you run `vim` it looks at your `PATH` to find the first executable with this name. It caches it and the second time you run `vim` it remembers `vim` is actually `/usr/bin/vim` and runs that.

Since you haven’t restarted your Bash session its cache is still the same; hence the error you’re seeing. It has nothing to do with the way you installed `vim`.

If you don’t want to start a new shell session, you can run `hash -r` to tell Bash to clear its executables memory.

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks @bfontaine - you the real MVP.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed to fix my vim +clipboard on OSX!

Comment: If you want to stay in the same window/tab/whatever, `exec bash` is an easy way to get a new shell session in the same place.

Comment: @jeremysprofile You can also run `hash -r` to clear the cache while keeping the same session.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot an argument:

```
$ brew install vim --override-system-vi
```

Comment: This option doesn’t exist.

Comment: @bfontaine, yes it does: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb#L14. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: I don’t think it doesn’t do what you think. `--override-system-vi` make the formula installs a `vi` binary that’s a symlink to `vim`. Technically it doesn’t override anything; we should probably rename it: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb#L99

Comment: @bfontaine is right; it installs a `vi` symlink to `vim`, nothing more. updated link to code: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vim.rb

Comment: `--override-system-vi` was deprecated; use `--with-override-system-vi` instead